# Repeatedly adding & removing rows from listbox eventually crashes with SIGSEGV

Tags: go, gtk3

I'm new to Go and GTK and have run into a problem with the app unpredictably crashing on GUI operations -- usually when Add()ing a row to a listbox. I think I've boiled the problem down to this simple example app which bounces back and forth between adding and removing rows to/from a ListBox. If you let it run for a few minutes, it will eventually SIGSEGV.

```
import (
    "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/glib"
    "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk"
)

func main() {
    gtk.Init(nil)
    win, _ := gtk.WindowNew(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    box, _ := gtk.ListBoxNew()
    win.Add(box)
    win.SetDefaultSize(200, 800)
    win.ShowAll()
    glib.IdleAdd(testAddRows, box)
    gtk.Main()
}

func testAddRows(box *gtk.ListBox) bool {
    for i:=0; i<40; i++ {
        label, _ := gtk.LabelNew("SPAM")
        row, _ := gtk.ListBoxRowNew()
        row.Add(label)
        box.Add(row)
        label.Show()
        row.Show()
    }
    glib.IdleAdd(testDeleteRows, box)
    return false
}

func testDeleteRows(box *gtk.ListBox) bool {
    for {
        row := box.GetRowAtIndex(0)
        if row == nil {
            break
        }
        box.Remove(row)
    }
    glib.IdleAdd(testAddRows, box)
    return false
}
```

Can anybody spot a problem with this code? I'm using Go 1.13, GTK 3, and the gotk3 bindings.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gtk but you might need to call `runtime.LockOSThread()` before doing GUI stuff. https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread I'd expect the Go implementation to mention this if it is the case.

Comment: Hi @zyl, I checked the gotk3 repository and LockOSThread is only mentioned twice, in two of their test cases. So, I gave it a try in the code above but still get the crash after a couple minutes. As far as I understand GTK3, the threading requirement is that all GUI operations be performed on the same thread that called GTK's init() and IdleAdd() allows one to queue a function to be run by that thread. So, I think I've got that right in the code.

Comment: Afaik go routines aren't assigned to a single thread, i.e. the thread which runs them might change at any moment. I don't have too many other ideas here unfortunately. Are you sure you don't need more explicit calls for destruction of GUI elements? Otherwise I'd recommend opening an issue on the project's Github page. https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/issues

Comment: The gotk bindings are supposed to manage the memory issues: "Care has been taken for memory management to work seamlessly with Go’s garbage collector without the need to use or understand GObject’s floating references."

Comment: If the main go-routine doesn't automatically lock to the main thread, then I think you're right about the need to LockOSThread() in order to satisfy GTK's threading rules. It's something I probably would have expected gotk to do in gtk.Init() or gtk.Main(), but I don't see it there.